# Can EntityFramework.dll run in GAC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want tranfer all public dll's to GAC, because I have many projects in one computer with other folders (services, applications).

I need to reference Entityframework from GAC...

1. I have test a project  Testrefs with  Model1 :DbContext.
2. Entityframework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll are referenced from pack.
3. I have a other install project with this code: 

   `var pbl = new Publish();
              foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
           {
                try
               {
                    pbl.GacInstall(assembly.FullName);...`

I runned this install for this dlls.
then they located:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntityFramework.SqlServer\v4.0_6.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntityFramework\v4.0_6.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\EntityFramework.dll

4. testrefs.csproj look like so: 
   `<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
   <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />`
5. Then i deleted   EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.xml,  EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml from App Folder.

On Form1_Load I got a table with .Tolist()
I runned, got this Exception:

> System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

If I copied  EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.xml,  EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml to AppFolder, runned normal.

I want EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll to GAC without Exception

How can I run a project referenced with EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and EntityFramework.dll on GAC

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac

Comment: The Question is not "Install to GAC"! I did it.   EntityFramework.SqlServer referenced in GAC. But on first loading throw this exception because EntityFramework.dll & .xml ,and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll & .xml are **not** in Application Folder.  EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll are in Properties Copy Local = false

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your .csproj file contents?